# Examples or Exercises on UNIX system calls?

Tags: unix

i am taking a course on UNIX system calls(file,process,I/O) etc. I would like to work on problems/exercises based on this so that i can familiarize myself on these topics.

Could anyone direct me to a link regarding the same? I tried googling for it, but couldn't find the one i was looking for. If you know any useful links, please let me know.

Thanks
Kelly

Answer (score 2):

System Call is a request for the operating system to do something on behalf of the user's program.  The system calls are functions used in the kernel itself.  To the programmer, the system call appears as a normal C function call.

Basic Example from a website : http://www.di.uevora.pt/~lmr/syscalls.html

```
 int main()
 {
    int i;
    extern int errno, sys_nerr;

    for (i = 0; i < sys_nerr; ++i)
       {
       fprintf(stderr, "%3d",i);
       errno = i;
       perror(" ");
       }
    exit (0);
 }
```

Many other useful (system calls) examples available over there.

Comment: None of the functions used in your example reside in the kernel. It is generally not specified whether a certain function wraps other functions or calls directly in the kernel, therefore the distinction between library functions and system calls seldom makes sense.